Can't boot with SSD plugged in after power loss while encrypting it
I was encrypting an SSD with Bitlocker when a power outage occured interrupting the encryption, when I powered back up the PC got stuck.
When the SSD is connected, the PC freezes on the initial boot screen, such as "Press F2 to enter BIOS," preventing further progress.
The BIOS cannot be accessed with the SSD connected, leaving the system stuck and unresponsive at the boot stage.
I already tried to use a SATA to USB adapter but it doesn't recognize the drive.
I also tried to plug the SSD SATA cable after boot but the disk management got stuck while scanning for disks; same thing happens if I try to do it with a live usb Linux.
Is there a way to wipe the SSD?

If the SSD is internal, then don't bother to put it in an external adapter.

Make a bootable USB rescue drive, such as Hiren's BootCD PE, Ultimate Boot CD (yes, they can both make a bootable USB drive), or an alternative.
Hold down F2, as you state, while booting to open BIOS.
Allow booting from USB, and change boot order to put USB first.
Press the key to keep setting changes (usually F10), and continue booting from USB. On some PC's, an additional key may need to be pressed to change boot order; see the manual.
The rescue disk should have tools, such as DiskGenius, GParted, or alternatives to enable reformatting the SSD. Easiest might be to do the following.

Remove all partitions from the SSD, making the whole drive free space.
Commit that action: most tools require confirmation, e.g., clicking a button to Save.
Restore Safe Boot or other changes made to BIOS to allow USB booting.
If you want to use that SSD for the primary operating system, e.g., Windows or Linux, then shut down, insert installation media, and let the OS installation format that empty space as part of the installation process.
Alternatively, partition the SSD as desired, commit the action, then format the partitions.



N.B. If this doesn't work, and the SSD cannot be seen by the repair tools, then likely the SSD has been destroyed. An SSD tends to fail completely, as opposed to gradual failure in HDD.
